# Nonlocal Gravitational energy: How to localize nontrivial topology in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wormholes, non-locality

Ok, This question has been beaten to death. I just wanted to look at it from a slightly different angle: Einstein, Rosen, and later Wheeler considered the possibility of particles as spacetime topology.

Suppose we had some spacetime containing a wormhole whose mouths were of small scale.

Perhaps we could describe them as having particle properties (perhaps not) let's put that aside for the moment.

What I'm really interested in is how one would describe the energy/momentum of said wormhole mouth given the nonlocal nature of gravitational energy.
Suppose we consider some closed surface around the wormhole, the region outside of which is flat (or of a cosmological metric solution).

In the limit of an infinitely small wormhole and bounding surface (a clearly nonphysical situation) , we might always transform it's gravitational pseudotensor to zero, leaving the energy/momentum entirely uncertain.
In the other extreme, we might have a wormhole distorting all of spacetime to some extent. In this case allowing the  gravitational pseudotensor to range over all spacetime will give us a (reasonably) well-defined Lorentz covariant quantity (Landau, Lifshitz).

Based on the two extreme examples, I would expect some kind of uncertainty relation regarding Gravitational energy/momentum and it's localization. How would I go about calculating the in-betweeen?
I understand that each (of the infinitely many) gravitational pseudotensors corresponds to a Hamiltonian boundary term, thus corresponding to a quasilocal quantity.[1](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/gr-qc/9809040/)

Comment: Hasn't the problem been recently solved for the mass and angular momentum in general relativity? I would expect that the solution strategy used in that work probably translates to momentum and energy.

Comment: @FlatterMann   is that the name of the paper? "mass and angular momentum in general relativity" is more of an introductory review than original research

Comment: I believe the science news was referring to the work of Chen, Keller, Wang, Wang and Yau published in 2021. I am not in the field and I did not read the papers myself. The reports claimed that they had found unambiguous definitions for mass and angular momentum, even though the mathematical proofs seem to have required something along the lines of a thousand pages. That is certainly far out of my range of ability and interest.

Comment: @FlatterMann Could link the article please?

Comment: @Rexcirus I am busy right now. I will try to get the references for you later.

Comment: @Rexcirus The most recent overview article (2022) seems to be "Conserved quantities in general relativity -- the view from null infinity" by Po-Ning Chen, Mu-Tao Wang, Ye-Kai Wang, Shing-Tung Yau (arXiv:2204.04010). I tried reading it, but it is way beyond my pay grade. As you can see, my initial comment was more of a question than a statement. When I took general relativity decades ago these questions were wide open according to my professors. They seem better understood now, but how much better (and at what level of complexity) that I can't judge.